# How to calculate average a dictionary from list of dictionary data?

Tags: python, dictionary, average

```
student_data = [{'id':1, 'Hacker' : 'DOSHI', 'Rank' : 43},
               {'id':2, 'Hacker' : 'JOSHI', 'Rank' : 45},
               {'id':3, 'Hacker' : 'MOSHI', 'Rank' : 41},
               {'id':4, 'Hacker' : 'LOSHI', 'Rank' : 98},
               {'id':5, 'Hacker' : 'AOSHI', 'Rank' : 14}]
```

1. Here I want to calculate average of 'Rank' ?
2. In other word, I want to get the average of (43,45,41,98,14)?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Do you know what a `for` loop is? Do you know how to access dictionary values? If yes, what's stopping you from attempting a solution? If no, well, this is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 1):

There're lots of ways to do this. You can try this explicit one:

```
student_data = [{'id':1, 'Hacker' : 'DOSHI', 'Rank' : 43},
               {'id':2, 'Hacker' : 'JOSHI', 'Rank' : 45},
               {'id':3, 'Hacker' : 'MOSHI', 'Rank' : 41},
               {'id':4, 'Hacker' : 'LOSHI', 'Rank' : 98},
               {'id':5, 'Hacker' : 'AOSHI', 'Rank' : 14}]
counter = 0
sumRank = 0

for i in student_data:
    sumRank+=i['Rank']
    counter = counter+1

average = sumRank/counter
print(average)
```

Also you can try this one liner solution (using `list comprehension`):

```
print(sum([i['Rank'] for i in student_data])/len(student_data))
```

Comment: No need for an intermediary list eating memory. Use a generator expression instead.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over your list of dict, and collect the 'Rank' value from each of it. Then compute the average.

```
>>> _list = [d['Rank'] for d in student_data]
>>> average = sum(_list)/len(_list)
>>> average
48
```

Or, even better as suggested by @timgeb

```
average = sum(d['Rank'] for d in student_data)/len(student_data)
```

Comment: No need for an intermediary list eating memory. Use a generator expression instead (and divide by the length of `student_data`).

Comment: You are right, but in this particular case there is very little memory to waste. Plus, I think the OP is still learning the basic skills, so I think this answer may help him approaching this kind of problems. Later on, he will deal with generators.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res_manual = sum(map(itemgetter('Rank'), student_data)) / len(student_data)  # 48.2
```

Or, vectorised, you can use a 3rd party library such as Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

res_pd = pd.DataFrame(student_data)['Rank'].mean()  # 48.2
```

Comment: I was trying to find a way using `functools.partial`, but `operator.itemgetter` is just perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This expression can be directly printed. We can get the sum of all of the values of key `Rank` by using `sum([i['Rank'] for i in student_data])` and we can get the number for our denominator by using `len(student_data)` which is equal to the number of `Rank`'s we summed, that will give us the average, which we can `print`

```
print(sum([i['Rank'] for i in student_data])/len(student_data)) # => 48.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a class to help projecting your dataset:

```
class π(list):
    def __getitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (a.__getitem__(*args, **kwargs) for a in self)
```

And then compute the average on the projection:

```
sum(π(student_data)['Rank'])/len(student_data)
```